# How to read values from an array inside a JSON array without keys?

Tags: java, android, json

How do I read the values from this json array and store those 2 values in 2 different variables?

```
[  
   [  
      6.89545,
      79.85217
   ],
   [  
      6.897287,
      79.859544
   ],
   [  
      6.905271,
      79.862609
   ],
   [  
      6.906114,
      79.858998
   ]
]
```

But, as is obvious, there is no key for the array. So how would one go about this? Is there possible way to deal with it?
This is the method i am using to get the values the from the array.

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        md.dismiss();
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray latLonArray = new JSONArray( response );

                for (int i = 0; i < latLonArray.length(); i++) {
                    // this is the part where I am stuck
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Server connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Server connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you already done? And what JSON library you are using?

Comment: You may use numerical index for retrieving them.

Comment: I updated my question. can you check it and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for (int i = 0; i < latLonArray.length(); i++) {
>                     // this is the part where I am stuck
>                 }

You can use numeric indexes to access values from your JSONArray. For example:

```java
 for (int i = 0; i < latLonArray.length(); i++) {

   double latitude = latLonArray.getJSONArray(i).getDouble(0);
   double longitude = latLonArray.getJSONArray(i).getDouble(1);

                }
```

Each element in the JSONArray is a JSONArray too and inside that JSONArray we have two double values (of course according to the structure of your JSON string) so you'll have to access the inner JSONArray and then retrieve its values. The above code may help, look at it and get inspired. Good luck.